# How to get code.xml file in /data/misc/sms/ directory of device?

Tags: android, android-4.2-jelly-bean

From CDD 4.2 document, it said: `Device that declare support for android.hardware.telephony` MUST warn users before sending a `SMS` message to numbers identified by regular expressions defined in `/data/misc/sms/codes.xml` file"

I try to get `codes.xml` file by `adb` command from that directory in both Emulator 4.2 and Galaxy Nexus 4.2 but both of them return that `codes.xml` file does not exist.
Could anyone tell me where that file is?

Answer (score 0):

It's not something that you actually have to do - the Android system takes care of warning the user. See this [video example](http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=nkND9edVszQ#t=78s) to see what it looks like.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, i've already try this on my device. But my problem is how to get the code.xml file (that contains regular expression warnings) from a real device. Do you have any idea?

Comment: You would probably need root access. However, here is the file that Android uses: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/a02bce1d5b3aafe359465eceaf3fd2a5b5b3918e/core/res/res/xml/sms_short_codes.xml

Comment: Yes, we could get that sms_short_codes.xml file from /framework/base/core/res/res/ of SDK. But this file doesn't contain regular warnings to user before sending a sms. 
Maybe we need root access permission to pull out code.xml file from real device. Thanks much for your help!

Comment: I need to confirm on rooted device first, then i'm happy to do that :P

Comment: Yeah that'd be great! I'd confirm myself but the only way to unlock mine voids my warranty... :/ and i'm guessing emulators won't contain it. I wonder if it would be available in source code tho (i.e. Samsung open source).

Comment: I check device with root permission but i still could not find out the code.xml on that location. Does anyone know?

Comment: The location of the file is stored in the `SHORT_CODE_PATH` constant as defined in (SmsUsageMonitor.java)[http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.2.2_r1/com/android/internal/telephony/SmsUsageMonitor.java#SmsUsageMonitor.0SHORT_CODE_PATH].